# Type of model inputs when using post-training quantization in TensorFlow Lite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, image-classification, quantization

I am implementing an image classification model in TensorFlow Lite with the intent to deploy with TFLite Micro on Arduino.

I am using post-training quantization in TensorFlow from float32 to uint8 with the following code. This specifies that the input type should be `tf.uint8`.

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
tflite_quantised_model = converter.convert()
```

In this case, do I need to use representative dataset images that have been re-typed to `tf.uint8`? Or does the quantisation process account for that, in which case I could use images of the float32 type?